# Cannot find hive odbc connector error messages using unixODBC

Tags: sql, ubuntu, odbc, hive, driver

I am trying to setup unixodbc to use the hive driver connector from cloudera (in an Ubuntu machine).

In my ~/.local/lib folder I have links to the .so files provided by cloudera,
also the env variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contains `/home/luca/.local/lib:/opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/lib/64/`.

I created the file /etc/odbcinst.ini containing the following:

```
[hive]
Description = Cloudera ODBC Driver for Apache Hive (64-bit)
Driver      = /home/luca/.local/lib/libclouderahiveodbc64.so
ODBCInstLib= /home/luca/.local/lib/libodbcinst.so
UsageCount  = 1
DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-16
ErrorMessagesPath=/opt/cloudera/hiveodbc/ErrorMessages/
LogLevel=0
SwapFilePath=/tmp
```

and in my home folder I have `.odbc.ini` containing:

```
[hive]
Driver=hive
HOST=<thehost>
PORT=<theport>
Schema=<theschema>
FastSQLPrepare=0
UseNativeQuery=0
HiveServerType=2
AuthMech=2
#KrbHostFQDN=[Hive Server 2 Host FQDN]
#KrbServiceName=[Hive Server 2 Kerberos service name]
UID=<myuid>
```

When I test the connection using `isql -v hive`
I get the following error message:

```
[S1000][unixODBC][DSI] The error message NoSQLGetPrivateProfileString could not be found in the en-US locale. Check that /en-US/ODBCMessages.xml exists.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

How can I fix this issue (why is the path absolute for /en-US/)?

Answer (score 1):

The SQLGetPrivateProfileString was not found in your ODBCInstLib library. Either the library could not be loaded, or the library did not contain the symbol.

Use `strace isql -v hive 2>&1 | grep ini` to see if your configuration file is being loaded. Use `strace isql -v hive 2>&1 | grep odbcinst.so` to see where it is looking for the library.

Make sure that the library exists in the given location and has the correct architecture. Use `file -L /home/luca/.local/lib/libodbcinst.so` to check the architecture. Use `nm /home/luca/.local/lib/libodbcinst.so | grep SQLGetPrivateProfilString` to check if it has the correct symbol.